# Finding average value in a single data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


l=[]
url = "ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/{}/Population.Heating.txt"
for i in range(1981,2018):
    df = pd.read_csv(url.format(i), sep='\|', skiprows=3, engine='python')
    l.append(df.loc[9])
print(pd.concat(l))


pd.concat(l)
Region      CONUS
19810101       28
19810102       29
19810103       33
19810104       37
19810105       38
19810106       33
19810107       31
19810108       36
19810109       37
19810110       36
            ...  

20171227       37
20171228       38
20171229       35
20171230       34
20171231       40
Name: 9, Length: 13551, dtype: object
>>>
```

This code will give temperature from 1981 to 2017, and I am trying to find the average value of each month

`pd.concat(l).mean()` didn't work....

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thank you!

Comment: if the index is datetime use `resample`, else use `grouper` with `freq="M"`.

Comment: This would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030171/how-get-monthly-mean-in-pandas-using-groupby

Comment: `df.loc[9]` will select a single row. is that what you want?

Comment: I just need the 9th row data for each csv file @PaulH

Comment: understood. i think this would be easier to diagnose if you just mocked up the dataframe to show us what it looks like. i keep getting name resolution errors when I run your code.

Comment: @PaulH 
I added my dataframe, too!

Comment: ok, all your need to do is parse the dates and do a basic resample. there are questions abound on SO about those very topic